# как указать несколько - CallbackQueryHandler

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot, handlers

Можно ли, как то указать несколько pattern-ов в CallbackQueryHandler

```
CallbackQueryHandler(func, pattern='smth')
```

или нужно создавать на каждый

```
CallbackQueryHandler(func, pattern='computer')
CallbackQueryHandler(func, pattern='mouse')
CallbackQueryHandler(func, pattern='monitor')
...
CallbackQueryHandler(func_two, pattern='apple')
CallbackQueryHandler(func_two, pattern='orange')
CallbackQueryHandler(func_two, pattern='strawberry')
```

Comment: CallbackQueryHandler(func, pattern=r'smth\d')

Comment: Цифры были для примера, а если там рандомные слова?

Comment: CallbackQueryHandler(func, pattern=r'smth.*')

Comment: Пришлось написать немного не красивую логику, но через regex получилось, спасибо